# database changes are not reflecting while deploying the .dacpac throught TFS 2015 CI/CD

Tags: tfs

I am doing CI/CD for database changes in my project for that  I created Database project in Visual studio 2015 and created new table and commit that changes in TFS 2015. Through CI i am building that project after building it is generating .dacpac .the generated dacpac i am deploying through released definition i am connecting to database and deploying the .dacpac but my changes are not reflecting i am not getting any errors or build or release failed.Not understanding where i am missing the connection? Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you please give us more information such as the steps in your build and release definition and how you've configured them?

Comment: In Build Definition : i am building the project throught MSbuild.

Comment: in Msbuild i am giving project reference and passing the below paramaeters in Msbuild Arguments

Comment: /t:build /t:publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=xxxxxx_Dev.publish.xml

Comment: IN Release 

I am using Windows Machine File Copy task to copy dacpac
from system default working directory to share folder

to deploy the dacpac from share folder i am using WinRM-Sql ServerDB Deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can [download an artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/artifacts) that contains your DacPac that your CI Build generates to your local development PC. You can then open the DacPac with the SSDT tooling in Visual Studio and run a [manual compare and publish](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690.aspx) against your target database. This will help you in investigating what is going wrong.

Comment: @mohankrishna Kindly share us your test result.